# Unity C# Getting info from Switch cases and using it in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a game for school and Im trying to get this data from the switch:

```
public void planets()
    {
        switch(PlanetType)
        {
            case planetType.Desert:
                Debug.Log("Desert");
                maxFuel = 500;
                break;
            case planetType.Ruined:
                Debug.Log("Ruined");
                maxFuel = 1500;
                break;
            case planetType.Lush:
                Debug.Log("Lush");
                maxFuel = 3000;
                break;
        }
    }
```

per scene for that specific planet as the maxFuel in the slider in that scene
I have the enum and that stuff, but for some reason in Unity, it only takes the input max fuel in unity and doesnt want to take the max fuel from the switchcase. Any quick fixes?

Comment: Please show more of your code. [mcve]

Comment: Where are you calling the planets() method?

Comment: I fixed it, I didn't call the planets() funtion :D. Now to make it show in the slider